# How to call coroutine from another script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been trying to start another coroutine on another object.

On the main object (Berserker), I need to call a coroutine on a small object named BerserkerHit. It's parented to Berserker.

I've tried

```
StartCoroutine(BerserkerHit.main.GetComponent<meshTimer>().Counter());
```

This didn't work, because the first space only excepts scripts.

So I tried

```
StartCoroutine(BerserkerHitbox.main.GetComponent<meshTimer>().Counter());
```

Which is the script. Then it said it had no definition for main. I removed main, and the entire thing started throwing an error. Fix?

Comment: Please provide further details such as the exact errors and the definition of the coroutine you wish to call.

Comment: What is main? Are you trying to reproduce the Camera.main reference? What is the error you are then getting after removing main? Is Counter properly defined as IEnumerator? Why are you not calling the coroutine from the hit object?

Answer (score 0):

You could call a function, then start the coroutine inside that function.

Ie, in the script you want to call the coroutine from:
Class.methodname();

And inside that method:
StartCoroutine(methodname());